# Sum values in dynamically created textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a table dynamically from user input (JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/XeuB8/11/)). I now want to sum up the textboxes in the table. To do this I have added a common class to all the input boxes and an id to the result textbox. However the onchange event is not firing when I enter a value in the textbox. What am I missing here?

Here is my JQuery for table generation code and textbox value sum:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#amortTable').click(function () {
        //User will input number of payments
        var i = $('#numOfRows').val();
        var s2 = "<table><th>Month No.</th><th>Cash Outflow</th>"
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            s2 += "<tr><td>" + (j + 1) + "</td><td><input type='text' class='payment' id='payment" + (j + 1) + "' /></td></tr>";
        }
        s2 += "<tr><td></td><td><input type='text' id='paymentSum' readonly='readonly' style='background-color:#C0C0C0' /></td></tr></table>";
        $('#amortizationTable').html(s2);
    });

    $('.payment').on("change", function () {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".payment").each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                sum += parseFloat(this.value);
            }
        });
        $('#paymentSum').val(sum);
    });    
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please consider adding `<tbody>` aswell when creating tables. IE as example would not render tables without tbody (old IE versions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:

```
$("#amortizationTable").on("change", ".payment", function () {
    // your code from above
});
```

Applied to your jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/XeuB8/17/

Notice I literally only changed 1 line (commented) and it seems to work.

The reason for this is because you bind the `change` event when the DOM is ready. But you are dynamically adding the rows (and `input` elements). Therefore, the new elements won't have the event bound to them.

The code I provided solves that by attaching one event handler to the table element. When anything fires a `change` event anywhere in the table, it checks to see if the element has the `payment` class. If it does, it executes the handler in its context. Otherwise, the handler is not executed for that `change`.

Here's the section about it in the jQuery docs for `on`: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: I was just about write the same thing as your edit in a comment. Thanks for updating with extra explanation or the OP.

Comment: @JeffShaver Haha yeah, I do that a lot - just want to get the immediate answer out there, then go back and explain :)

Comment: @OP: you might also want to use "keyup" instead of change, or you won't see the effect untill the input loses focus

Comment: @DanielV Very true, there's a lot that could be changed, but I just wanted to fix the immediate problem. The OP is free to add/remove events they want to use for this functionality, but it's not up to me for what they truly want. Although it is misleading when the OP says "the onchange event is not firing when I enter a value in the textbox" - which makes me think they want the `onkeyup` event. At the same time, this should fix the dynamic problem they're having. If they respond with something regarding seeing the effect sooner, `onkeyup` should be an addition, definitely!

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for the explanation. That cleared up a basic concept :).

Answer (score 0):

The "change" event for '.payment' is not firing. I would suggest putting the sum logic within the click handler.